# Android web service call throws org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java, android, web-services, exception, http-post

**WHAT I DID:**

I have tried to call the web service by **"POST"** method from my android app using the following code.

```
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myserver.com:5060/convert/service");
       try {
           File file = new File(inputPath);
           httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
           httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/pdf");
           httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(readFile(file)));

           // Execute HTTP Post Request
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

When I do this api call, I am getting the following exception.

> "org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to
>   respond"

But when I do the **same web service** call from **standalone java project** using the **same code**, I am getting the **correct response**.

Not getting any errors like above.

**WHAT I WANT:**

Based on my **java web service call**, I know that there is **no issue in service and also the source code**. So What may be the issue? How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("my service url"); are you sure that `my service url` needs to be in quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

The issue is because of **port number 5060**. I did found this by using **TCP/IP monitor** tool in eclipse.

By defaule **5060 port** is not being called from android(**I didn't know the reason**). Because the request not hits the server.

So I have changed the **port number to 8090** in my server and restarted the server.

Then I called the service from android. Now It's working great.